# No compatible servers were found - MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows-installer, installation, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install MySQL Server, mysql-installer-community-8.0.19.0.msi, on Windows 10.

I download the latest version from
[MySQl::MySQL Downloads](https://www.mysql.com/downloads/)

These are the screenshots:

[image: Screen 1]

I selected *Full*:

[image: Screen 2[![][3][3]]

I think something went wrong here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this usually happens because you did not install the requirements manually in the previous steps. I recommend that you uninstall and install back again. After that, you will click on these items to try to resolve them manually. It performs the installation of Visual C +++ 2019
[check the image of the step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh3rj.png)

Comment: Make sure you uninstall the previous installer, this worked for me on Windows 2019 Server.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was getting the error because MySQL server was not installed because it had a missing requirement, Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable Packages, as I installed it. This error was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the problem as you did.
And the reason was, as you guess, the check requirements section.
By pushing the button of Execute, some processes are conducted and
the problem is solved.